# Riccati-type recurrence: infinitely many sign changes?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, sequences-and-series

Suppose $b_1, b_2, b_3, \dots \in \Bbb{R}$ satisfy the Riccati-type recurrence
$$b_{k+1}=\frac{1+kb_k}{k-b_k},\quad k\ge 1.$$

> Is it true that such a sequence reaches infinitely many positive as well as negative values? It appears to be so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, choose $a_1$ such that $\frac{1}{b_1}=\tan(a_1)$, and let $a_{k+1}=a_k-\arctan\frac{1}{k}$, then we have $\frac{1}{b_k}=\tan(a_k)$, since $\sum_k \arctan\frac{1}{k}=\infty$, the conjecture follows.

Comment: Note that if $b_1=0$ we can take $a_1=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Not sure if this proves the claim.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan where makes it "not sure"? You mean $b_i$ may be zero ? If you mean this, its my fault. I should write it as $b_i=cot(a_i)=tan(\frac{\pi}{4}-a_i)$.

Comment: It's very nice. If you need more details, the sequence $a_k$ is decreasing to $-\infty$ with jumps going to 0, so its tangent achieves infinitely many change signs. The trick is quite natural: your homographies can be viewed in the projective line (given by rotations), and with a coordinate changes this can be viewed as standard rotations, which after taking these parameters (on the universal covering), yield translations.

Comment: Yes, a great comment!

Comment: Thanks, but it is possible that the $a_k\rightarrow-\infty$ and yet $b_k>0$ all the time. This needs justification, I presume.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan As is explained by YCor in his comments before, $arctan\frac{1}{k}\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$, while the sign changes once you go $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $a_k$ can't just skip a   $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and keep the sign of $b_k$,

Comment: The argument gives you in addition an estimate in the number of consecutive steps with a given sign.